# IE warning - Microsoft Office Contact Retriever

Tags: 2010, security, internet-explorer

When I open a SP 2010 page with IE 10 on Windows 8, I get this warning:

> Internet Explorer Security
>
> A website wants to open web content using this program on your
>   computer:
>
> Name: Microsoft Office Contact Retriever

What is the purpose of this program, and is it safe to allow it?